# Application of graphing relationships

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The mayor of Sickville realized that out of its $19,950$ residents, only $10$ are physicians. He is thinking about bringing more physicians into town in order to increase this density, which doesn't need to be more than $3$ physicians per $1000$ people.
He wanted to graph the relationship between the number of new physicians and the number of physicians per $1000$ people.

Which axis should represent the number of new physicians?

Potentially, mathematical variables can have any value, but the variables under discussion here are bounded by the real-world context they model.

What is the range of valid values for the number of new physicians?

Even though I feel stuck with this problem, I have a few ideas. Since the number of physicians per $1000$ people would be a much smaller value should that not be the horizontal axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which axis should represent the number of new physicians?

Although there are exceptions, we usually put the "independent variable" on the horizontal axis. This is the causative variable, the one that can change on its own or from causes outside the current scope. The dependent variable, the one that changes because the other variable changed, is on the vertical axis. The variable with the smaller value is usually irrelevant for choosing the axes.

Since the cause is bringing in new physicians, the number of new physicians should be the horizontal axis.

> What is the range of valid values for the number of new physicians?

Your statement "this density, which doesn't need to be more than 3  physicians per 1000  people" is unclear as to whether the density is *allowed* to be greater. Let us assume that the statement is indeed a limit on the highest value. We then get

$$\frac{10+x}{19950+x} \le \frac{3}{1000}$$

When solved, we get

$$x \le 50$$

We obviously cannot bring in negative physicians, so our "range of valid values for the number of new physicians" (actually the domain) is

$$0 \le x \le 50$$

Strictly, we should also add that $x$ is an integer, since we cannot import portions of a physician--at least, not legally or morally.